# Element-wise matrix division in Matlab is returning only binary values

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix

I am reading two images as matrices in Matlab and want to create a third image, which is calculated as:

```
(im1-im2)./(im1+im2)
```

However, I believe Matlab is rounding the values of the element-wise division (which of course I don't want). For example, the first value of `im1-im2` is **32** and the first value of `im1+im2` is **70**. So, the first value of the resulting matrix is supposed to be `32/70=0.4571`, but it is **0**.

How can I do this matrix operation maintaining the original division result values in the final matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your image data and how you load it. An 8-bit image loaded e.g. with `imread`, is stored as integer matrix (`uint8`). Images with higher bit-depth are stored with `uint16` or more.

So you could either process your image by casting the matrix to `double` and cast it back to an appropriate bit-depth afterwards, or you cast it directly to your desired bit-depth and accept the rounding, as it needs to be done anyway at the end.

```
im1 = double( imread('fig1.png') );
im2 = double( imread('fig2.png') ); 

result = uint32( (im1-im2)./(im1+im2) );
```

Comment: I solved the problem by using single(im1-im2)./single(im1+im2). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`im1` and `im2` are `uint8` or `uint16` most likely, convert them to `double` and perform this operation. Note that converting them implicitly like `*1.0` or something doesn't work.

So, something like

```
im1 = double(im1);
im2 = double(im2);
thingYouWant = (im1 - ...;
```

Note that converting back to `uint` will again leave you with 1 (values above 0.5) or 0 (values below 0.5). To convert back to `uint8`, you need to do something like:

```
resultInUint8 = uint8(thingYouWant * 255); % Linear scale from 0 to 255
```

Another thing to note is that `double(im1 - im2)` will result in 0 if `im2` is larger than `im1`. So you might end up with half of image being 0. Better to convert before doing any operation.

Comment: That's probably C-Code? But no valid Matlab Syntax.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Yeah you are right, mixed up notation with c#. Fixed.